Permission monitoring.timeSeries.list denied (or the resource may not exist)
I am working with google cloud project (Nodejs server). I need to collect the metrics "monitoring.timeSeries.list" from google cloud using  "googleapis".
When i try to request API with my service account Authen Default Credential its return
status: 403,
  code: 403,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Permission monitoring.timeSeries.list denied (or the resource may not exist).',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'forbidden'
    }
  ],

I have already provided "Owner" Role for that service account and downloaded it's .json file .
But When i run API with "gapi" on my browser with my "Owner" user account, it works well.
Code with service account on server with "googleapis":
const authenticate = async () => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
    scopes: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.read",
    ],
  });
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();
  google.options({ auth: authClient });
  return authClient;
};
const queryMetrics = async () => {
  try {
    const authClient = await authenticate();
    const monitoring = google.monitoring({
      version: "v3",
      auth: authClient,
    });
    const projectId = instanceData.projectID;

    const request = {
      name: `projects/${projectId}`,
      filter: `metric.type="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"`,
      "interval.startTime": "2024-05-08T03:14:51Z",
      "interval.endTime": "2024-05-08T03:15:51Z",
    };

    const response = await monitoring.projects.timeSeries.list(request);
    console.log("Metrics data:", response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error querying metrics:", error);
  }
};

Code with user account on client with "gapi":
const authenticate = () => {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn({
      scope:
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.read",
    });
  };

Does this API cannot perform by service account or I did something wrong?.
Thank you for reading!

you need to give the monitoring role access to the corresponding IAM user.
Monitoring Viewer role, this role is for only read purposes.
